# Travelling into Schengen area after 'intended' travel date

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas

After getting my Schengen Visa (6 months), my travel plans changed and now I am going to non-schengen countries first before my official arrival at a Schengen country. However this makes my entry date into the schengen zone about two weeks later than what I applied in the application form and my visa start date. Would this pose any issues possibly now or when I apply for Schengen again?

Comment: Not a problem. There is no "intended entry date" on the visa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your visa has a **validity period** and a **duration of stay** (up to a maximum of 90 days out of every 180). If your changed trip falls within the validity period, not much of a problem. However, the first use of a multiple-entry visa should match the purpose from the application. If a business meeting was postponed or a vacation comes slightly later, that's fine, that's why they give longer validity than duration.